# Executar nome de função contida em variavel (PHP)

Tags: php, funções

Estou montando uma aplicação que executa uma função com o seu propio nome
No caso a pagina Contato teria que executar a função ContatoCtl() só que ela está em uma variável $metodo.
Como que eu executaria esta função?

```
$ctlclass = 'Contato';
$metodo = $ctlclass.'Ctl()';
$this->$metodo;
```

**CODIGO ACIMA RETORNA O SEGUINTE ERRO:**

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aplication\Contato.php

Answer (score 2):

O `$this` é uma **Pseudo-variável** do PHP, ela funciona diferente das demais variáveis, e quem manipula ela á a máquina virtual do PHP. O `$this` aponta para um objeto na memória, ou seja, o objeto que está em execução. Olhando para o seu trecho de código, aparentemente você não está dentro de uma classe, com isso você não conseguirá utilizar o `$this`.

Comment: Eu imaginei que esse poderia ser o problema, só que como eu executaria a função ContatoCtl() ?